# Wrong choice of radio-buttons transmitted to CakePHP-controller

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, radio-button

Got a strange problem where the checked="checked"-attribute is ignored and Cake always receives the value="1" after form submission.

The Code for the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('INCOMETYPE', array(
    'legend' => false,
    'value' => '1',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'options' => array('1' => 'Festbetrag', '2' => 'pro Stunde', '3' => 'Naturalien')
));
```

Which prints:

```
<div class="input radio required">
    <input type="radio" name="data[Post][INCOMETYPE]" id="PostINCOMETYPE1" value="1" checked="checked">
    <label for="PostINCOMETYPE1">Festbetrag</label>
    <input type="radio" name="data[Post][INCOMETYPE]" id="PostINCOMETYPE2" value="2">
    <label for="PostINCOMETYPE2">pro Stunde</label>
    <input type="radio" name="data[Post][INCOMETYPE]" id="PostINCOMETYPE3" value="3">
    <label for="PostINCOMETYPE3">Naturalien</label>
</div>
```

what actually should work like a charm. But:

When the user checks a radio with value 2 or 3 the checked-attribute of the first won´t go away and none of the newly checked radios get the checked-attribute. At submission the controller therefore receives value="1" everytime.
The second strange thing is: When a checked-change is forced via jQuery like that:

```
$('#PostDEADLINE1').click(function() {
    $('#PostDEADLINE1').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#PostDEADLINE2').attr('checked', false);
    $('#PostDEADLINE3').attr('checked', false);
});
    $('#PostDEADLINE2').click(function() {
    $('#PostDEADLINE1').attr('checked', false);
    $('#PostDEADLINE2').attr('checked', 'checked');
    $('#PostDEADLINE3').attr('checked', false);
});
    $('#PostDEADLINE3').click(function() {
    $('#PostDEADLINE1').attr('checked', false);
    $('#PostDEADLINE2').attr('checked', false);
    $('#PostDEADLINE3').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

The controller gets the value="1" as well. It seems like the jQuery-approach doesn´t have an effect at all.
My question: How can I get a working example of radio-buttons in Cake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is found. The browser doesn´t keep visual track of the checked-attribute. Internally the correct checked-state of the users´ choice is set. After debugging those two params everything was fine and in my controller I did wrong stuff with the request-data:

```
debug($this->request->data['Post']['DEADLINE']);
debug($this->request->data['Post']['INCOMETYPE']);
```

You don´t need to use jQuery for that stuff of course.